# Получить все Buttons с помощью Reflection

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Как можно получить все объекты класса Button, которые есть в exe файле? 
Если есть ссылка на окно - то еще вроде ничего, но если ее нет - то возникают проблемы. 
Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69204/discussion-on-question-by-torsen---buttons---reflection).

Answer (score 1):

Забыл отписать о решении.
К сожалению не получилось сделать через MergedDictionary и ResourceDictionary, о котором говорил @VladD, но в целом - получилось и оказалось куда проще чем я думал.

```
        App cur = (App)Application.Current;
        Style grayStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
        grayStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Gray));
        ....
        Application.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(Button), grayStyle);
```

Единственное что - необходимо чтобы до этого не было заданно никаких стилей для элемента.